# Jsf Managing Beans With Spring Framework

Tags: spring, jsf

I'm using JSF in my project and i have 2 beans marked with
@Component and @Scope annotations. My problem is i want to share a value between beans but it doesn't work. I mean when i set a value in first bean i want to read that value in second bean but when i try it, it throws Null pointer exception even i use ManagedBeans and managedProperty. I'm too exhausted and still struggling with this problem but i can't fix it.
I can't share my code because of privacy issues but i need help.
Thanks.

This is my first bean:

```
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Component("firstBean")
    @Scope("view")
    @ManagedBean(value = "firstBean")
    @SessionScope
    public class FirstBean{ 
    private String name;
    }
```

when i set name in firstBean i want to read that value in second bean like (firstBean.name) but it throws NPE

```
    import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Component("secondBean")
    @Scope("view")
    @ManagedBean(value = "secondBean")
    @SessionScope
    public class SecondBean{
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{firstBean}")
        private FirstBean firstBean;
    }
```

Comment: @JasperdeVries i edited and it says firstBean is null in secondBean so that i can't read name field from firstBean